# How do I open webp files with Microsoft Photo App?

Tags: windows-10, file-association, photos

I want to use the Windows 10 "Photos" app to view webp files.

"Photos" is a Microsoft App, and I can not open up C:\Program Files\WindowsApps.
It is security protected.

Because of that, I can not select Open With -> Photos.

How could I achieve this anyways?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge "Microsoft Photo App" does not know how to handle these files. How do you want the app to understand webp. Do you have some kind of add-on?

I'd suggest, that you try it first directly via the app.

To answer your question: it is difficult. You might take ownership of the folder but I would advise you to not do it.

You might try it with a "hack" where you create a softlink to the executable via cmd.

1. **cmd with elevated rights**: Open the start menu, search for "cmd" right click -> start as administrator
2. **search the app**: with elevated rights you can use "cd" and "dir" to find the app. Mine is in  `cd %PROGRAMFILES%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_<bunchofnumbers>` and the exe is called `PhotosApp.exe`
3. **go to target place**: use cd to a "safe" place, i.e. one you can easily access as a user. I use `cd %localappdata%\programs`
4. **link the app**: Use "mklink" to create a softlink. `mklink PhotoAppLink "%PROGRAMFILES%\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_<bunchofnumbers>\PhotosApp.exe"`

(You can also skip 3. and use an absolute path in 4. And actually you only need the elevated rights to find the name and location of the executable. Linking (strangely) is possible without.)

Afterward you can chose this file in the "Open With" menu.

Answer (score 2):

Try the official codec for Windows:
https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/WebpCodecSetup.exe

Using the codec you will be able to open webp files using the Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Running WebpCodecSetup.exe will install the older Windows Photo Viewer app. It does not add a codec to the Windows Photos app. After installation the Windows Photo Viewer app can be chosen as the default image viewer. So this is strictly speaking a work-around but not a solution to what the OP asked.

Comment: And even within the Windows Photo Viewer, it appears to be rendering the webp differently (more contrast) than other applications (including the one exporting the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can technically associate **webp** with the Photos app using the following registry code (save the code as a .REG file if you wish to try it).
However, as of January 2023, it seems that Photos does not yet handle **webp** files, I checked both Windows 10 and Windows 11 versions.
I managed to get Photos to open a **webp** file when double-clicking on it, but the window is empty, the photo is NOT displayed. As others have pointed out, replacing the extension to PNG does work, but obviously this is only a workaround instead of a real solution.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;; It may be required to replace HKEY_CURRENT_USER with your UserSID HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-XXXXXXXX

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\PackageRepository\Extensions\windows.fileTypeAssociation\.webp\AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc]
"Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2022.31120.6008.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"=""
;; Maybe should be "Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp\OpenWithProgids]
"AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"=hex(0):


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.webp\OpenWithProgids]
"AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"=hex(0):


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.webp]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.webp\OpenWithList]
"a"="Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"
"b"="msedge.exe"
"MRUList"="ab"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.webp\UserChoice]
"Hash"="X/7LWBvQfgQ="
"ProgId"="AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how, but a fresh Windows 11 Installation seems to handle webp out of the box now. Can't save it, but can open it like others.